# Can't get qwt_designer_plugin to load in Qt Creator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt-creator, qwt

My setup is:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Qt 5.2.0 from
  http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-msvc2012-x86_64-offline.exe
- Unzip Qwt from http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt/6.1.0/qwt-6.1.0.zip/download to C:\qwt-6.1.0
- Opened Qt 5.2.0 64-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2012) and ran "qmake qwt.pro"
- Opened VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and ran "nmake" and "nmake install"
- Set QWT_ROOT = C:\qwt-6.1.0
- Added C:\qwt-6.1.0\lib to PATH
- Copied C:\qwt-6.1.0\plugins\designer\qwt_designer_plugin.dll to C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer

When I open Qt Creator and edit the UI then go to Tools->Form Editor->About Qt Designer Plugins I see "Cannot load library qwt_designer_plugin.dll:" but no error or reason.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Dependency Walker to check the Dll, and QtCreator.exe and all its dependencies are 32-bit whereas my build of qwt_designer_plugin.dll is 64-bit. I wondered if this was causing the problem so I:

- Downloaded Qt5.2.0 from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-msvc2012-x86-offline.exe and install into C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0-32
- Unzipped Qwt into C:\qwt-6.1.0-32bit to create a fresh copy.
- Opened Qt 5.2.0 32-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2012), cd into C:\qwt-6.1.0-32bit and "qmake qwt.pro"
- Opened VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt and ran "nmake" and "nmake install"
- Copied C:\qwt-6.1.0-32bit\designer\plugins\designer\qwt_designer_plugin.dll to C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer

This works fine and I can now see the plugin loaded correctly and add Qwt widgets in the UI designer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

---

**Step 1**

I check what MSVC version the QtCreator in my Qt framework version was built with. E.g. QtCreator that comes with Qt_5.6.2 **MSVC2015** (qt-opensource-windows-x86-**msvc2015-5.6.2**.exe) was built with **MSVC 2013** (qt-opensource-windows-x86-**msvc2013-5.6.2**.exe).

[image]

---

**Step 2**

I install qt-opensource-windows-x86-**msvc2013**-5.6.2.exe and build Qwt(plugin) with that Qt version.

For comparison here is what happens when Qwt is built with Qt_5.6.2 **MSVC2013** and Qt_5.6.2 **MSVC2015**:

[image]

---

Also here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20156419/3096593

---